# Access RotatedRect center value?

Tags: android, c++, opencv

i need to convert following C++ code to opencv based android and access center of the "rect" 
'result" is mat object. i'm having error here.

```
ArrayList<RotatedRect> rects = new  ArrayList<RotatedRect>();
for(int i=0; i< rects.size(); i++){
  core.circle(result, rects[i].center, 3, Scalar(0,255,0), -1);
}
```

Comment: If you were writting the error message, we would know where to look.

Comment: `rects[i].center` i think the syntax is wrong. ones i put as  `rects.center(i)` core.circle function error with missing parameters

Comment: Do you have an error during compilation ? Because rects.center(i) is clearly not correct, or C++ on android is a really weird c++

Comment: error  `The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<RotatedRect>`
but i need to keep my rects varible as RotatedRect.

Comment: My bad, arraylist indeed, I misread vector. Berak is right.

Answer (score 0):

it's an ArrayList, not a simple array, so use:

```
rects.get(i).center; // not rects[i]
```